# Creating a MySQL table with PHP include connection

Tags: php, mysql

**Im trying to build a database with php.

Here is what am I doing:**

*db_connect.php*

```
<?php
    $db_connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "mydb", "", "");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "Successful database connection, happy coding!!!<br/><br/>";
    }
?>
```

*db_create_table.php*

```
<?php
include_once("db_connect.php");

$tbl_users = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
            id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
            userlevel ENUM('u','m','a') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'u',
            avatar VARCHAR(255) NULL,
            ip VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
            signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
            lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
            activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (id),
            UNIQUE KEY username (username,email)
            )";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $tbl_users);

if ($query === TRUE) {
    echo "Table 'users' is created!<br/><br/>"; 
} else {
    echo "Table 'users' is not created!<br/><br/>"; 
}
?>
```

**And this is the result:**

*Successful database connection, happy coding!!!*

*Table 'users' is not created!*

**Can someone help me with this, I don't know where is my mistake :(**

Comment: Check the docs on the mysqli functions. There are also functions to get more detailed error information, so you get a clear error message that tells you why you can't create the table. It could be a syntax error, it could be permissions, but the actual error message will probably shed some light on it.

Comment: Try "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.users

Comment: Is it intentional `avatar VARCHAR(255) NULL,` ?

Comment: You didn't specify a database name when you called `mysqli_connect()`. Either specify a default database there, or include the database in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the db name  as the db user, it must be like this:

```
$db_connect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some arguments missing in calling `mysqli_connect()`? According to the [function document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php), the meaning for each argument is that:

- first: Database address
- second: access username
- third: access password
- fourth: default database/schema